# Why the result looks strange when I send different parameters to the same function? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My view is like this :

```
...
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: -10px;margin-bottom: 5px" href="{!! route('users.create.year', [$year]) !!}">
    Add New
</a>
...

...
@foreach($testArray as $key)
...
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{!! route('users.create.year', [$key['display'], $year]) !!}">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</a>
...
@endforeach
...
```

My routes is like this :

```
Route::get('users/create/{year}/{display?}', 'UserController@create')
     ->name('users.create.year');
```

My controller is like this :

```
public function create($year, $display = null)
{
    echo $display.' : display <br>';
    echo $param_thang. ' : year';die();
    ...
}
```

When I call url like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/create/2016`, it works.

There result is like this :

```
: display
2016 : year
```

When I call url like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/create/14144499452111901/2016`
The result is like this :

```
2016 : display
14144499452111901 : year
```

It looks strange, the result is reversed

Why did it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your route is:

```
Route::get('users/create/{year}/{display?}', 'UserController@create')
 ->name('users.create.year');
```

So the first parameter is always going to be the year, and the 2nd parameter is always going to be the display variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `<a>` as @farkie suggested:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{!! route('users.create.year', [$year,$key['display']]) !!}">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Seems you master laravel. I need yo help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887504/how-to-solve-missing-argument-1-for-app-repositories-favoriterepositorydelete/41887543