# How to solve Missing argument 1 for App\Repositories\FavoriteRepository::delete() ? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My service is like this :

```
public function delete($store_id)
{
    $result = $this->favorite_repository->delete($store_id);
    dd($result);
}
```

My repository is like this :

```
public function delete($store_id)
{
    $data = self::where('favoritable_id', $store_id)->delete();
    return $data;
}
```

There exist error :

> Missing argument 1 for App\Repositories\FavoriteRepository::delete(),
>   called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\app\Repositories\FavoriteRepository.php on
>   line 45 and defined

Can you help me?

**UPDATE**

The delete function in the EloquentRepository is like this :

```
public function delete($id)
{
    // Find the given instance
    $deleted  = false;
    $instance = $id instanceof Model ? $id : $this->find($id);

    if ($instance) {
        // Delete the instance
        $deleted = $instance->delete();

        // Fire the deleted event
        $this->getContainer('events')->fire($this->getRepositoryId().'.entity.deleted', [$this, $instance]);
    }

    return [
        $deleted,
        $instance,
    ];
}
```

Comment: which class does `App\Repositories\FavoriteRepository` extend ?

Comment: @Angry Coder, EloquentRepository

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: @Angry Coder, I had update my question

Comment: @Angry Coder, `App\Repositories\FavoriteRepository` : `public function delete($store_id)
{
    $data = self::where('favoritable_id', $store_id)->delete();
    return $data;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using this pakage: `nilportugues/eloquent-repository`

If that is the case then you need to change the repository code to this:

```
public function delete($store_id)
{
    return $this->remove($store_id);
}
```

Comment: If it does not use conditions `where`?

Comment: There exist error : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::remove()`

Comment: are you using `nilportugues/eloquent-repository` this package ? check in your composer.json file

Comment: No. I use `rinvex/repository`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked which instance is returning your `self::where('favoritable_id', $store_id)`? It seems it is returning your EloquentRepository instance, instead of Model instance.
The difference is that EloquentRepository's **delete** method is `delete($id)`, the Model's **delete** method is `delete()`.
So you either need to get Model instance to use ->delete(), or use ->delete($id) on yours